# Compare data from 2 files having million records in Python

Tags: python, compare

I have 2 files old.txt and new.txt containing hundreds of thousands of data(near about 1.2 million keys and respective amounts)

new.txt

```
key |amount
abgc-nhd|8976
mkis-plqa-d|-254
mjsnh-kis-ls|987
njud-lo-sa|5291
mkjsh-kis-ls|686
mjsnh-fis-ls|387
njudd-kid-ls|-876
nswxd-lo-sa|3191
mki-ksjd-as|-56
```

old.txt

```
key |amount
mkjsh-kis-ls|686
njudd-kid-ls|-876
abgc-nhd|8976
mjsnh-kis-ls|987
njud-lo-sa|5291
mjsnh-fis-ls|387
mkis-plqa-d|-254
nswxd-lo-sa|3191
```

I want to compare these two files.

i.e.I want to check whether the key in the old file matches the key in the new file.If yes then i have to compare their amount.

I tried by inserting all values into a dictionary and then checking whether the entries exists,but this takes a longer time and the system gets hanged.

Is there any another way to compare the two file on the basis of key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use pandas, you can do as follows:

```
new_txt = """key |amount
abgc-nhd|8976
mkis-plqa-d|-254
mjsnh-kis-ls|987
njud-lo-sa|5291
mkjsh-kis-ls|686
mjsnh-fis-ls|387
njudd-kid-ls|-876
nswxd-lo-sa|3191
mki-ksjd-as|-56"""

old_txt  = """key |amount
mkjsh-kis-ls|686
njudd-kid-ls|-876
abgc-nhd|8976
mjsnh-kis-ls|987
njud-lo-sa|5291
mjsnh-fis-ls|387
mkis-plqa-d|-254
nswxd-lo-sa|3191"""


import pandas as pd
import io

df_new = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(new_txt), sep="|")
df_old = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(old_txt), sep="|")

print(df_new - df_old)
```

This gives for the example data:

```
abgc-nhd           0
mjsnh-fis-ls       0
mjsnh-kis-ls       0
mki-ksjd-as      NaN
mkis-plqa-d        0
mkjsh-kis-ls       0
njud-lo-sa         0
njudd-kid-ls       0
nswxd-lo-sa        0
```

The `NaN` indicates that this key is present only in one set.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('new.txt') as infile:
    records = {}
    for k,v in csv.reader(infile):
        records[k] = int(v)

with open('old.txt') as infile:
    for k,v in csv.reader(infile):
        if records[k] != int(v):
            print("There is a mismatch in key", k)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, I see that the entries in the files are not sorted. So, one solution which will be fast is to sort the entries of the file, if the order does not matter, and compare the lines in both files.

After sorting, say, the line1 in file1 starts with "abm..." & the line1 in file2 starts with "bcn...", then there is no need to check the remaining entries that starts with "a..." against the lines in file2, since there is no such thing.
Proceed to the next line and check like this for all the remaining lines. Also you could print those lines that only match and write it into separate file. This file will only have the lines that has "common" keys, as you want.

This algorithm should be faster than O(n^2).